# Powerpoint VBA: split the main slide deck into two slide decks

Tags: python, vba, powerpoint

I'd like to learn an automated way to split one slide deck into two: one for the main slides and the other for the appendix. It can either be distinguished by the "appendix" section in powerpoint, or the slide that has "appendix" text in it. The end results I'm expecting are one deck for main slides and the other deck just for appendix. I have 10+slides to perform this task on a reoccurring basis. Some slides don't have the appendix section, so it could just stay as is in the output.

I'm open to Powerpoint VBA or python code or any other free tools.

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a macro-writing service. Start by searching on terms like _PowerPoint VBA split file based on sections_. When you get down to debugging the details, post your code here and we'll help you.

Comment: What @JohnKorchok said. As a starting point, write a function that looks at each shape on a slide, tests to see if it contains text and if so, does the text include the string "appendix". If so, the function returns True, otherwise False.  Have your code save a copy of your presentation to a new name, step through the slides backwards (important), pass each slide off to the function above and if it returns true, delete the slide. Then repeat the process but this time save the slide if the function returns true, delete it otherwise and save.